# Set the property of a class using decorators on a class method in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class `ABC`, inside it there is a function `someFunction`.

I do not want to mess up with the code of `someFunction`, thus I wrap it with a `@MyDecorator`. How can this `MyDecorator` modify the property of the class `ABC` when I call `someFunction`?

```
class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.someProperty = "Initial value"

    @MyDecorator
    def someFunction(self):
        print "Hello world"


class MyDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...??? 
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

abc = ABC()
abc.someFunction()  #   When calling someFunction(), abc.someProperty would be updated
```

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you expect to happen when you call `abc.someFunction()`? If it's supposed to change `abc.someProperty`, why not do that directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
class MyDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        instance.someProperty = "New value"
        return self.func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.__call__.__class__(self, instance)

class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.someProperty = "Initial value"
    @MyDecorator
    def someFunction(self):
        print("Hello world")
```

`MyDecorator` is now a [*descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) since it implements `__get__`.

When an attribute of any instance of `MyDecorator` is accessed through some class or an instance of that class, `__get__` will be called.

`__get__` will receive an instance of that owner object in the parameter `instance`, from there we can return a new instance of `instancemethod` that will receives that `instance` implicitly:

```
>>> abc.someFunction.__class__
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> abc.someFunction.__class__.__doc__
'instancemethod(function, instance, class)\n\nCreate an instance method object.'
>>>
```

It requires a `function`, basically any callable object will work, because `MyDecorator` is class, `__call__` will revise its own `self`.

In action:

```
>>> abc = ABC()
>>> abc.someProperty
'Initial value'
>>> abc.someFunction()
Hello world
>>> abc.someProperty
'New value'
>>>
```

Note in Python 2.X, `MyDecorator` must be a new-style class that inherits `object` or that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define MyDecorator earlier in the file than where you use it, or you get "NameError: name 'MyDecorator' is not defined".

I was wrong when I said "a decorator should return a function". That applies to functions used as decorators, as in my example.  However, when a class is used, it doesn't have to return a function as such.  It returns an object in that class.  It might be less confusing if "class MyDecorator" were named "class MyModifiedFunction" instead, because an element of the class is used as the decorated function.

Usually, the function returned by the decorator will call the original function.  Yours doesn't.  It doesn't have to if you want to totally replace someFunction rather than just modify it.

You don't need to make MyDecorator a class.  You could make it a function.  Here's an example:

```
def MyDecorator(original_function):
    def replacement_function(*args, **kwargs):
        args[0].some_property = some_new_value
        return(original_function(*args, **kwargs))
    return(replacement_function)
```

Follow this by the first half of your code, where you define class `ABC`.

Note that when it says `return(original_function(*args, **kwargs))` it's running the original function and returning whatever the original function returns.  If the original function returned an object, it would return that object.  However, when it says `return(replacement_function)` it's doing something quite different:  it's not running the replacement function at that time; it's just returning the function as the return value.  A decorator has to return a function.

(@dano: Good point. I fixed it, I think.)

Here's the above suggestion in more complete form:

```
def MyDecorator(original_function):
    def replacement_function(*args, **kwargs):
        args[0].some_property = 'Modified value'
        return(original_function(*args, **kwargs))
    return(replacement_function)

class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_property = "Initial value"

    @MyDecorator
    def some_function(self):
        print "Hello world"

abc = ABC()
abc.some_function()  #   When calling some_function(), abc.some_property wou
```

ld be updated

```
print "some property is", abc.some_property
```

I ran this and it works; it prints

```
Hello world
some property is Modified value
```

so this verifies that it did indeed modify the some_property in abc.  It's accessed as `args[0].some_property`, because when the decorated function is called (as an object method), `self` is passed in as the first argument.

Comment: You should `return` the result of `original_function`. It won't cause any issues with the OPs example, but it would if the decorated method returned something.

Comment: The reason I made `MyDecorator` a class is here: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808 . It is more flexible than making it a function IMHO :) Thank you for your answer anyway! Cheers